# How to convert n most significant bits in a hexadecimal byte string in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, binary, hex, byte, decode

In Python 3, I am using PySerial to read two bytes and I would like to get the decimal representation of the 11 most significant bits in those two bytes.

This is a print of two bytes that I get from my serial communication as an example:

```
b'\x1e@'
```

Those two bytes have the following binary representation:

```
00011110 01000000
```

I want to keep the 11 most significant bits, here shown without leading zeros:

```
11110010
```

And convert the result to a decimal value, or `242` in this example. Can anyone help me perform this conversion in Python 3? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Shift right by 5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert the data to an integer and shift five bits:

```py
data = b'\x1e@'
print(int.from_bytes(data) >> 5)
```

Output:

```
242
```

Ref: [`int.from_bytes()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.from_bytes)